# Conversion issue for a long string of integers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, parseint

I'm trying to convert a long string which has only integers to numbers.

```
var strOne = '123456789123456789122';
parseInt(strOne, 10);
// => 123456789123456800000

var strTwo = '1234567891234567891232';
parseInt(strTwo, 10);
// => 1.234567891234568e+21
```

The expected output should be the same as `strOne` and `strTwo` but that isn't happening here. While converting the string to a number, the `output` gets changed.

What's the best way to fix this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, your number is too long to fit in a JavaScript Number and gets wrapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) is now available in browsers.

> `BigInt` is a built-in object that provides a way to represent whole
>   numbers larger than 253, which is the largest number JavaScript can
>   reliably represent with the Number primitive.
>
> **value** The numeric value of the object being created. May be a string or an integer.

```js
var strOne = '123456789123456789122';

var intOne = BigInt(strOne);

var strTwo = '1234567891234567891232';

var intTwo = BigInt(strTwo);

console.log(intOne, intTwo);
```

Comment: @NinaScholz [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#Browser_compatibility). See also  [BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js); [BigInt: arbitrary-precision integers in JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/bigint); [JSBI - pure-JavaScript BigInts](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi#why);

Comment: @guest271314: I'm not sure why that response to comments from NinaSholz, who correctly points out that there are important browsers not supporting this.  The compatibility chart says the same.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Is Edge "important" to you? Why? Have not used *indows or IE in some time and have not yet had the occasion to use Edge once.  Who cares if MS browser does not support a useful feature. Use a FOSS browser that does. In any event see the linked libraries. Now, if those libraries do not return the same result as the built-in `BigInt` at Edge, you can file an issue with MS to get that fixed and `BigInt` implemented at Edge.

Comment: I don't use them myself, with Linux at home and Mac at work.  But I develop applications that still need to support them.  [Wikipedia reports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers#Summary_tables) a combined desktop share for IE and Edge of 14% and overall combined share of 5%.  I'm glad to know BigInt is as widespread as it is, but it's some ways from ubiquity.

Comment: @ScottSauyet A large percentage of people drink soda pop containing HFCS and  eat 50-day chickens which are harvested at a rate of 2600 per second. That does not mean an individual has to consume those products because they are inexpensive or "taste good". Here, advise clients to purge IE when they are still using them at their desktop in the 21st century where at least Mozilla Firefox is available; and Chromium is somewhat FOSS (save for their decision to record user biometric information and send that data to a remote server without notice in their `webkitSpeechRecognition` implementation).

Comment: @guest271314: I think we live in different worlds.  I work for a company selling software and services to large financial firms.  A vendor who won't write software that will work in their environment won't sell software.  Many of them are still using IE11 or Edge.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Same world. We evidently make different choices. Yes, that is how monopoly capital works to sustain itself and profit. Not everyone buys in, is already bought, or can be bought. Your insight is revealing. Is the vendor held responsible when the companies are compromise, perhaps due to using hardware or software that is outdated and fully mapped for exploitation? Or does the insurance companies then get their piece of the manufactured issue of intentionally deploying legacy technologies? Your perspective re "won't" is why EMV chips have been accepted by populations without question

Answer (score 2):

You number is unfortunately too large and gets wrapped when the conversion is done.

The largest integer you can express in JavaScript is `2^53-1`, it is given by `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, see the [MDN doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

> The reasoning behind that number is that JavaScript uses double-precision floating-point format numbers as specified in IEEE 754 and can only safely represent numbers between -(2^53 - 1) and 2^53 - 1.

```js
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
```

If you want to work with numbers bigger than this limit, you'll have to use a different representation than `Number` such as `String` and use a library to handle operations (see [the BigInteger library](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js) for example).

Comment: But that doesn't mean there aren't approaches to working with larger numbers